# HTC M8 (6.0.1): TreeSet<Long>.contains(Long) throws class cast exception: "cannot cast Double to Long"

Tags: java, android, classcastexception

We've just received a crash report that I honestly don't understand, and I'm not even sure if it's a good question as such... but I can't think of anything.

I have the following code:

```
public class LeisureEventSelectedCategories {
    private Set<Long> ids = new TreeSet<>();

    public boolean contains(Long id) {
        if (id == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return ids.contains(id);
    }
```

Where the line `return ids.contains(id)` crashes with the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at java.lang.Long.compareTo(Long.java)
    at java.util.TreeMap.find(TreeMap.java)
    at java.util.TreeMap.findByObject(TreeMap.java)
    at java.util.TreeMap.containsKey(TreeMap.java)
    at java.util.TreeSet.contains(TreeSet.java)
    at com.acme.b.a.d.a(LeisureEventSelectedCategories.java:50)
```

The `Long` I receive here is from a `Map<String, Long>`.

```
leisureEventSelectedCategories.contains(eventCategoryNameToEventId.get(categoryName)) || leisurePlaceSelectedCategories.contains(placeCategoryNameToPlaceId.get(categoryName)),
```

Where

```
Map<String, Long> placeCategoryNameToPlaceId = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Map<String, Long> eventCategoryNameToEventId = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

Apart from replacing the `TreeSet` with a `HashSet` and using `Collections.sort()` where I need it, what could be causing this and how should I avoid it in the future?

**EDIT:**

image of values in `leisureEventSelectedCategories` after selecting all items that come from server:

[image: LeisureEventSelectedCategories values]

image of values in `eventCategoryNameToPlaceId`

[image: eventCategoryNameToEventId values]

Comment: not possible with that code...  show us instead how are you calling the ***contains*** method

Comment: I did show how I call the `contains` method... and I know it shouldn't be possible, but I did get a crash report with this exception >.> i'm going to replace the `TreeSet<Long>` with a `LinkedHashSet<Long>` as immediate bug fix

Comment: Btw I could not produce this crash on either a Samsung device nor my Nexus 5X.

Comment: can we see the return of this ***eventCategoryNameToEventId.get(categoryName)***?

Comment: I've added two images that show what data was / can be in the two mentioned fields. In debugger when the photo was made, `categoryName` is `Music`. I do not know what was the value of `categoryName` at the time of the crash. (on the picture the set is now a `LinkedHashSet` but this used to be the `TreeSet` that crashes on HTC M8)

Comment: Wow that is crazy... where could be the Double object coming from  ?? LOL

Comment: Dude I have no idea XD

Comment: there must be something else you are not posting...

Comment: There isn't. >.< I checked too. This is the code. This is the data. The only code I don't have is the code for `TreeSet` on HTC M8. Unfortunately I do not own the device so I cannot debug it on that device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, we just replaced it with `LinkedHashSet<Long>` and the crash is gone.